Voltage amplifier for a triangular wave using 2N222 BJT
My task is to amplify the voltage of a triangular wave which is between 100mv and -100 mv, so I design a common emitter circuit to do it, but when I check the vout I see that my output wave is already above 0v, and it seems to be like a borderline where I can´t reach some value below 0v, why is that bad for me? 
This circuit needs to pass a task that is about measuring 3v when I disconnect the source, and the signal must be between 5 and 1 volts, so it is literally impossible to me to complete this two task simultaneously, because if I wanna to have the output between this to values, I need to put the gain in 4v and put an offset of 1v to reach it, but then if disconnect the source, I only get 1v. In the other case if put 3v of offset, then the lowest value of my signal will be 3v.

here I have the results.

So in summary any value that I put it in the output voltage as offset won´t count as the medium point of my wave but its minimun value.

If I put the 3v of offset that I need onn the outpu,then my wave will be above that value.


Do you have any idea what is happening with the circuit?

Don't worry about the title.  Tell us more about your project.  What are the requirements for the project?  What is the required amplifier gain?  Does the output have to go above and below GND, or can it be a clean uni-polar (all above GND) waveform?  What is the load on the output?

Define the required output more accurately for +/- 0.1 V input along with source and load impedance.

sure, the resistance of 18k is the load, can´t be changed, neither the 4k source resistance, the output must be between 1v and 5v and the input its just +/- 0.1 v, R4 is a resistance to put an offset on Vout, but If I put the 3v that I need on the output, the wave go above 3v.

Define the  output tolerance when you expect inverted sawtooth 5 to 1 V and output when input disconnected pls.

+/- 1 volt of tolerance, thinking that the real resistors have an expected value but in reality have another one,

when input is disconnected is should be 3v

Your specs are conflicted and insolveable.

But this does it as long as the input stays connected.   https://tinyurl.com/29eqk7ww.  :)

In the CircuitLab simulator your initial circuit does not work at all. The DC setpoint had a very low collector voltage, clipping most of the input signal.
The used models for 2N2222 may be very different.
I changed RE to get more gain and R2 to define a better DC operating point.
Fine tuning of R4 adds the required DC offset to the output.
In a real world circuit this would be done using an OpAmp, because the DC gain of the transistor varies from part to part and there are temperature drifts.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The collector headroom looks ok here (orange track) and the output (brown track) has the desired characteristics.

